# Programmatically adding Adobe PDF viewer to new tab

Tags: c#, pdf, tabs

I'd like to be able to open multiple documents at the same time in tabs, to do this, I need to be able to programmatically. How I did the following code:

```
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);`
```

Is how I'd like to add the PDF viewer in place of the RichTextBox. I'm just not sure how to add the viewer programmatically. Any help or a push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Lane if you want to view pdf file in new tab. You don't need to open pdf viewer. Pdf files can be easily open in browser. so set tp.content= rtb. Thanks

Comment: @Pawan That would work, but I have a specific need for the PDF Viewer. If I cannot find a way to add one, then I will definitely try to rework my program to work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Just download [ITextsharp.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Unblock this dll. Right click in itextsharp.dll. Go to Properties. At the bottom click on unblock.

Right click in your project in solution exploral. Click Add Refference. Select the location where you saved itextsharp.dll. Add this in your project.

Now write the following lines.

```
PdfReader reader
            = new PdfReader("Your content here");
```

Hope this will help. You can also visit this [Link](http://jadn.co.uk/w/ReadPdfUsingCsharp.htm). Thanks

Comment: "Inaccessible due to protection level", "Cannot convert from PdfRreader to system.windows.forms.control" and I seem to be having a problem with my add tab control.

Comment: try something other equivalent to tp.Controls.Add(). I think it allows only forms control to add. Or you can use pdfreader inside a window form control like a rectangle. Add Rectangle inside this use Pdfreader then use tp.controls.Add(rectangle). Try something like this.

Comment: I believe I have found a solution to this using AxHost Class to add the Adobe PDF Reader as a Windows Form Control. I'm testing it now. If it works, I'll come back and post the solution.

Comment: Will wait for solution